# How to block loadbalancer forwarding to a specific path?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have multiple albs that is routing to path specific locations. How can I block a specific path such as :

```
alb1.com/path/*
alb2.com/path/*
alb3.com/path/*
```

without having to create a separate empty target group and assigning it to each of the rule separately since one target group can only be assigned to one alb.

Comment: What response are you seeking to send to the client - 404 page does not exist, redirect or don't respond at all?

Comment: 404 does not exist

Comment: @JohnHanley do you think you can help me?